# How to call a function in VS Code with a click

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I know we can test methods with Jest and some plugins so you just run the test and it calls whatever function you want, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this with a plugin or trick, to call a function just with clicking on it or by a command via terminal.

Comment: I don't think this exists, it would be a good open source project for someone though :)

Comment: You can use the JavaScript Debug Terminal to debug Node.js processes. View the Run panel by selecting View > Run. There's just too much context that goes into calling functions to make calling it by clicking on it practical.

Comment: the only function to call that way is a function without arguments that only has side effects, like the main function of the application, so just run the application